# Add a DNS Record in CloudFlare using C#

Tags: c#, dns, cloudflare

I wish to access **CloudFlare** from my C# code and **add DNS records** to it. I am using the **CloudFlare API** and have found the following code to achieve my goal:

```
CFProxy.Dns.Add("example", "127.0.0.1", "example.com", DnsRecordKind.CNAME, 1);
```

However, as I run the program it gives the error :

> Zone does not exist.

Anybody familiar on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you actually using those values? `example.com`?

Comment: @Rob Nope. I just placed "example" here as a placeholder for my actual values. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work through the existing code that I have.

After a series of researching and trial-and-error, I found out that I was passing **incorrect arguments** to the Add parameters of CFProxy.DNS.

As in the example, "example.com" is a domain/URL that is **not a recognized zone** in my **CloudFlare account**. That's why it kept on returning the error "Zone does not exist."

You must first identify as to which zone/domain your CloudFlare account has from where you can add records. Below is the correct one:

```
CFProxy.Dns.Add("example.name.com", "site.namesite.com", "name.com", DnsRecordKind.CNAME, 1);
```

> WHERE:
>   **example.name.com** = is the name of the site URL you wish to add ;    **site.namesite.com** = is the site URL/IP you would like to put the alias on ; **name.com** = is the zone/domain where you add records in your CloudFlare account.

And ofcourse the other 2 parameters are for what record type you wish to add (as in this case, **CNAME**) and **1** for **Automatic TTL**.